# Error when pressing back button

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextfield

I have a navigation based app with views that allow edit of text fields  if I click on a text field and then press the back button before the done button I get.

CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: *** -[CALayer setContactTelephone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3c2f280

by textFieldDidEndEditing method does run, it attempts to resignFirstResponder.  Has anyone seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

Where in your code do you send the `setContactTelephone:` message to an object?  That object is probably being deallocated prematurely (perhaps in `viewWillDisappear:`?), and the message is being sent to a CALayer that happened to take its place in memory.